# AS3:: Loading SWF issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader

I have some problem by loading an SWF.

This is my code

```
if (stage.contains(myLoader))
{
    myLoader.content['onRemove']();
    stage.removeChild(myLoader);
}

urlReq = new URLRequest("rent_.swf");
myLoader.load(urlReq);
stage.addChild(myLoader);
```

And everythings works fine. But when i try to add an Event.COMPLETE listener, then I get the error 1009

```
if (stage.contains(myLoader))
{
    myLoader.content['onRemove']();
    stage.removeChild(myLoader);
}

urlReq = new URLRequest("rent_.swf");
myLoader.load(urlReq);

function completeRent(e:Event):void{
    stage.addChild(myLoader);
}

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeRent);
```

I've allready checked the code in rent_.swf and everything is fine there.

The problem appears only when I add the Event.COMPLETE listener.

I wan't to put a preloader to load this SWF.

Can anyone Help?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

There is the corrected code:

```
if (stage.contains(myLoader))
{
    myLoader.content['onRemove']();
    stage.removeChild(myLoader);
}

urlReq = new URLRequest("rent_.swf");
myLoader.load(urlReq);
stage.addChild(myLoader);

function completeRent(e:Event):void
{
    //some tweens
}

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeRent);
```

In this form, everythnig worsk fine!

Comment: useless code anyway since you don't have to wait for event.complete to add your loader to the stage.

Comment: I learnt from this back in the day.. **[Preloader tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/)**. Just scroll down  to the coding part to get hints on how its done correctly (with no code issues)

Comment: I've resolved it by taking out from function completeRent() the: stage.addChild(myLoader); :line, and putting it before that function. Thanks for help!